# Content load only after fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load content in between **fadeOut** and **fadeIn**.

If I try to run the following code the content loads before the **fadeOut** finishes:

```
$("#contentArea").fadeOut(1000);
$("#contentArea").promise().done();
$("#contentArea").load(content_map[$(this).attr('id')]);
$("#contentArea").fadeIn(1000);
```

I have tried to put a callback function in the **fadeOut** but still, the **load** inside that callback was called early. I tried to add a **setTimeout** after the **fadeOut** and it still didn't work.

I added the **promise** function (which is critical apparently), with or without a callback function holding the follow-up actions, but it did not work.

I will be happy to know how best to achieve this effect and if someone can also give me a tip as to why my other attempts failed it will be a wonderful bonus :)

Comment: `.done();` without a callback?

Comment: I experimented with promise and done... placing the fadeIn inside the done callback allowed me to delay the fadeIn until all the elements were faded out. But when I tried it this way (fadeIn after the done), it still worked... I have no idea why.

Comment: In your example, even if you remove `.promise().done()` it will work exactly the same way since the later `.fadeIn` will stack on the animation queue of `#contentArea` **after** `fadeOut`. If instead you really want to use Promise `.done()` - than place the other methods and functions inside the `.done(fnCb)` callback

Comment: removing the promise call in the above example resulted in a weird behavior... that ended with the #contentArea div hidden (even though the fadeIn came after fadeOut).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function should work, so I suspect you did it wrong. It should be:

```
$("#contentArea").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).load(content_map[this.id], function() {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: You are right, I also didn't know that the load function has a callback function... thanks a bunch!